# An RSS feed has mysteriously disappeared in a chat room I own

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, feed

The [Board and Card Games chat room feeds info](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/49/board-and-card-games?tab=feeds) indicates that there are 3 feeds (the tab title is "(3) feeds"), but it only lists two. [I added a third feed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/49?m=23815269#23815269) a while ago, but it has failed to post the most recent news articles it should be posting.

Comment: Assuming your feed is http://magic.wizards.com/en/rss/rss.xml (please, in future, specify the actual feed you're adding), it doesn't actually validate correctly: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http://magic.wizards.com/en/rss/rss.xml

Comment: It was working, though. It posted several articles, and then stopped at some point. And regardless of what the feed was, the fact that it is counted in the feeds tab number but not listed on the page is a bug. I couldn't tell if the feed had been removed, or just hidden from the listings, or something else.

Comment: Well, they changed the format of the feed, then. It isn't valid (the date format is wrong; I tried putting in a hack to massage the dates to see if it were the only blocker, but it also contains relative URLs, which feeds aren't allowed to contain), so it will not process successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in chat build 314.

After 50 failures to process a feed that used to work, or 20 failures to process a feed that has never worked even once, it's disabled. The feeds page does not show disabled feeds, but the Feeds tab still counts disabled feeds in its count. Now, I've changed the code so that disabled feeds are not counted.